How to know user is online/offline with django channels?
With Django Channels, can you track which users are online or offline throughout your website? Should every page have a websocket connection? And when a user is online/offline, how can I show the user online/offline in real time.
I have no idea. I only do group chats online users but cant do user online/offline in full website

Does your chat app requires authentication for sending messages or not?

Yes it requires

To show users as online/offline in real-time, you can update their status in the database when they connect/disconnect from the WebSocket. You can periodically check the user's connection status by monitoring their WebSocket connection or using heartbeat signals. Here I will use heart beat version(here i assume that you have an app named chat) :
First of all, create a model that store user state which is last_activity
like this one :
chat/models.py
class UserActivity(models.Model):
    user          = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    last_activity = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def update_activity(self):
        self.last_activity = timezone.now()
        self.save()

If you need more fields, add them and don't forget to add it into your admin panel. Now, you need a middleware to check the user is online or not.
chat/middleware.py :
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.utils import timezone

from chat.models import UserActivity


class UserActivityMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):    

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            UserActivity.objects.update_or_create(user=request.user, defaults={'last_activity': timezone.now()})


Now add this middleware after, Auth middleware like this :
core/settings.py :
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',    
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    
    # Here your middleware should go
    'chat.middleware.UserActivityMiddleware',
]

Pay attention, Your middleware must be activate after a user logged in. Now you can use this model in which ever way you want, and gets user information in which view that you need.
